# notepad++ search in range

Tags: search, notepad++

i have a huge file containing numbers with decimals that looks like this

```
31.3043 31.3043 31.3043 31.3043 31.3043 31.3043 31.3043
200 200 200 200 200 200 200
121.739 121.739 121.739 121.739 121.739 121.739 121.739
10.4348 10.4348 10.4348 10.4348 10.4348 10.4348 10.4348
5.2174 5.2174 5.2174 5.2174 5.2174 5.2174 5.2174 5.2174
```

what i only want to search is for the numbers above 10

```
31.3043 31.3043 31.3043 31.3043 31.3043 31.3043 31.3043
200 200 200 200 200 200 200
121.739 121.739 121.739 121.739 121.739 121.739 121.739
10.4348 10.4348 10.4348 10.4348 10.4348 10.4348 10.4348
```

excluding numbers

```
5.2174 5.2174 5.2174 5.2174 5.2174 5.2174 5.2174 5.2174
```

Comment: this worked [0-9]{2,6}+(\.[0-9]{1,6})?

Comment: You can use regex for that case excluding all lower numbers then 10

Comment: @user2644715 When I try your regular expression on `5.49382` it matches the decimal part.

Comment: so far it worked though, anything below two digits is not searched and i was able to replace everything that is not 9 and below

Answer (score 1):

This does the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<![.\d])\d{2,}(?:\.\d+)?`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Search</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<![.\d])  : negative lookbehind, make sure we have not digit or dot before current position
\d{2,}      : 2 or more digits
(?:\.\d+)?  : optional non capture group, for decimal part
```

Comment: This is, symbol for symbol, the exact same regex I had in my head. That is so weird.